# Filtrado de fechas en un dataframe dado un rango de fechas

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

a ver si me podéis ayudar con este problemilla que tengo.
Imaginaos que tenemos un dataframe de una serie de trabajos que se tienen que hacer en una empresa y tiene dos columnas una con la fecha inicial de los trabajos(“Inicio”) y otra con la fecha final(“Final”)
Lo que quiero es saber como hacer para ver que  trabajos hay entre dos fechas dadas.
Por ejemplo:
fecha_1=”15/09/21” y fecha_2= “18/0921”
Quiero que me filtre en el Data Frame las filas cuyas fechas entre “Inicio” y “Fin” coincida en algún día entre las fechas de fecha_1 y fecha_2
Por ejemplo si una fila tiene Inicio = 13/09/21 y Fin= 16/09/21 tendría que filtrarla porque coincidiría con algunos de los días que están entre fecha_1 y fecha_2.
No se si me he explicado bien. Espero vuestros comentarios. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues tengo la suerte de que hace poco hice algo muy similar pero para otro lenguaje y creo que podría orientarte. A continuación pongo un esquema en Excel de cómo debería funcionar lo que pides (ojo, es cómo debería funcionar, no la estructura del dataframe)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las barras amarillas representan la duración de un proyecto. Por ejemplo, el Proyecto 3 tendría fecha de inicio 22/01/2021 y fecha final 06/08/2021. Esto, aplicado a tu dataframe significaría que `Inicio=22/01/2021` y `Final=06/08/2021`

Por otro lado, en la imagen se ven 4 zonas de color diferenciadas: una gris arriba, luego verde, otra morada y finalmente una azul

Por poner un ejemplo, la zona verde equivaldría a que quiero ver todos los proyectos que, de alguna manera, su **vigencia** esté comprendida en el tramo `fecha_1=19/02/2021` y `fecha_2=07/05/2021`. Los proyectos con vigencia en ese tramo serían:

1. Proyecto 1
2. Proyecto 2
3. Proyecto 3
4. Proyecto 6
5. Proyecto 8
6. Proyecto 9
7. Proyecto 10

El resto de proyectos (por ejemplo, el 5) no tocan la zona verde y serían filtrados.

Con esta estructura en mente sí es posible establecer un patrón matemático y establecer un código en Python funcional. Sin embargo, como no has puesto código de ejemplo ni dataset ni nada, solo puedo hacer una aproximación.

Si nos fijamos en la zona verde, s**olo quiero ver aquellos proyectos que cumplan 2 cosas a la vez** (condición AND):

1. `Final>=Fecha_1`, es decir, tienen que terminar después de que **inicie** la zona verde (ojo, incluso si terminan después de la zona verde)
2. `Inicio<=Fecha_2`, es decir, el proyecto tiene que haberse iniciado antes de que **termine** la zona verde (ojo, esto significa que el proyecto se ha iniciado durante la zona verde o incluso antes de la zona verde).

En ambos casos, el tramo determinado por `Fecha_1` y `Fecha_2` abarcaría las vigencias determinadas por `Inicio` y `Fin`

Con todo esto en mente, puedes beneficiarte de la propiedad LOC de los dataframes:

> [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Como dije antes, no puedo poner un código 100% funcional por la falta de información en tu respuesta, pero debería ser algo así:

```
df.loc[(df['Final'] >= Fecha_1) & (df['Inicio'] <=Fecha_2)]
```

Es lo más aproximado que puedo dar.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tan excelente y trabajada respuesta. Me ha servido de mucho y me ha funcionado a la perfección.  Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @JesusCarrera Me alegro que te sirviera. Por favor, marca la respuesta como correcta para que se quede cerrada la pregunta, :) [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)